# Conocer de dónde viene (dominio) una conexión con mi servidor ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Tengo un servicio ASP.NET Core en un servidor GNU/Linux con la siguiente configuración de inicio:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Proyecta.PPlus.Web.Helpers;

namespace Proyecta.PPlus.Web.Startup
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(opt => opt.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIIS()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseUrls("https://*:5001")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

En `CreateWebHostBuilder` le paso `.UseUrls()` para definir las URLs aceptadas como conexión (`.UseUrls(https://*:5001)` acepta conexiones desde cualquier IP siempre que se cumpla el puerto y SSL, `.UseUrls(https://mydomain.com:8000)` aceptaría solo conexiones que vengan conecten a ese dominio...).

Hasta aquí todo claro, este servicio tendrá una serie de dominios por los que se conectarán los clientes y, en función de ese dominio se realizarán unas u otras opciones.

```
.UseUrls("https://domain1:5001")
.UseUrls("https://domain2:5002")
.UseUrls("https://domain3:5003")
.UseUrls("https://localhost:8080")
```

Mi duda es, ¿cómo puedo saber a través de dónde se conectan para poder configurar estas acciones?. Si se conectan a `domain3` o `localhost`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar lainformación alojada en la `request` del `context`:

`HttpContext.Request.Host` return the domain like `domain1:5001`.

Si sólo quieres el nombre del dominio o el puerto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

`HttpContext.Request.Host.Host` para obtener únicamente el nombre del dominio, devoleviendo: `domain1`

`HttpContext.Request.Host.Port` para obtener únicamente el puerto, devoleviendo: `5001`.

He añadido esta funcionalidad al controlador de `Login` para realizar la lógica pertinente:

```
        public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "", string ss = "")
        {
            [...]

            if (HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.ToString().Equals("domain1"))
            {
                [...]
            } 
            else if (HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().Equals("127.0.0.1:9229"))
            {
                [...]
            }
            else
            {
                [...]
            }

            return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });
        }
```