# Redirección de puertos en PC industrial Linux

Tags: linux, debian, redirección

Tengo un PC industrial (Debian) al que puedo acceder por una dirección dentro de una VPN. A parte, el PC tiene una red local interna (`192.168.1.0/24`). Me interesaría acceder temporalmente al servicio web de un elemento en la red local (192.168.1.3:80), pero no tengo acceso directo a ese equipo; y el PC industrial no tiene interfaz gráfica para verlo desde él.

He leído que podría redirigir un puerto del PC para que me lleve al otro elemento.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes probar con el comando `redir`, es simple y quizás suficiente para lo que necesitas.  Si no lo tienes instálatelo en el Debian.

Answer (score 2):

Según lo veo, es una redirección simple de puerto a puerto. Si tu PC no tiene servicio web publicado en el `80` (`http`) puedes aprovecharlo para redirigir al mismo del elemento que está en la dirección `192.168.1.3/24`.

Si tienes `socat` instalado, puedes simplemente utilizar:

```
sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork TCP4:192.168.1.3:80
```

Donde `TCP4-LISTEN` hace referencia al puerto local (del PC) y `TCP4` a la `dirección:puerto` del elemento.

En caso de no tener instalado `socat` o no querer usarlo, puedes usar directamente ìptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.3:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Recuerda que estos comandos los ejecuta el PC que hace de gateway entre la VPN y la red local. Así, podrás acceder desde el navegador escribiendo la dirección `http://direccion-vpn:80`.

Ten en cuenta que si el servicio fuera `https`, debes sustituir el puerto `80` por el `443`.

Comment: ¿Nos parecemos en qué?

Comment: Espero que en nada, pero mirando esta [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308547/conocer-de-d%c3%b3nde-viene-dominio-una-conexi%c3%b3n-con-mi-servidor-asp-net-core/567401#567401) veo que eliminastes una respuesta clavada a la que te dio este mismo usuario dias despues de dártela, por eso lo he dicho.